# Populate combobox from category in view

Tags: xpages

I am trying to populate the values of a combobox from a single category in a view:

```
<xp:panel>
    <xp:this.data>
        <xp:dominoView var="view1"
            databaseName="myDb.nsf"
            viewName="myView"
            keys="myCategory">
        </xp:dominoView>
    </xp:this.data>

    <xp:comboBox id="comboBox1" value="#{myDoc.someField}">
        <xp:selectItem itemLabel="Not Assigned" itemValue="" />
        <xp:selectItems>
            <xp:this.value>
                <![CDATA[#{javascript:view1.getColumnValues(1)}]]>
            </xp:this.value>
        </xp:selectItems>
    </xp:comboBox>
</xp:panel>
```

I have tried with both `keys="myCategory"` and `categoryFilter="myCategory"` but both settings return ALL the values in the column instead of just the values for the given key/category.

I suspect `getColumnValues()` doesn't actually respect either `keys` or `categoryFilter`, but is there an alternative?

I could always manually populate a scoped variable in `afterPageLoad` and have the combobox refer to it, but I would prefer to "wire it together" with the control properties because the list can be changed elsewhere on the page.   Is this possible?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15026710/get-column-values-of-searched-filtered-view-results

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, getColumnValues is not a method of the View class. I think there are two (three) possibilities:

1. use plain old @DbColumn or @DbLookup (available in JavaScipt!)
2. or equivalent code in JavaScript (or Java) using getAllDocumentsByKey
3. the same, but use createViewNavFromCategory to build a ViewNavigator and walk through its entries

Comment: `@DbLookup` in SSJS is very slow. In formula language it's a direct call to underlying platform code. SSJS is just a wrapper for Java, and `@Functions` in SSJS are wrappers for API code in SSJS which are wrappers for the Java API code. Avoid `@Functions` and use object oriented APIs instead. Not only is it better performing, it minimises the learning curve and refactoring when moving to Java or Node.js.

Comment: @D.Bugger if getColumnValues is not a method of NotesView shouldn't it throw an error?  The combobox is working, it's just not giving me what I expect/want. Nonetheless, it looks like I will just have to add some looping code to build the list.  It's not a big deal; I was just hoping for a simpler solution.

Comment: Oops... you are correct, it is indeed a (new) method of NotesView. One learns every day... But apparently, it doesn't respect the category you selected. I agree with you in that it seems to me an inconsistency too. As for a solution, the only methods that come close to what you want are getAllDocumentsByKey and getAllEntriesByKey, both with multiple keys.